# Expose host-only minikube for local network

Tags: virtualbox, expose, host-only

I have 2 pc:

1. Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 LTS
2. Windows

I installed minikube + virtualbox (host-only) on 1). When I deploy app on minikube I can't reach it from pc 2) (because host-only I guess).

How can I expose minikube app for pc 2) ?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by this commands:

```
minikube service hello-minikube
kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 service/hello-minikube 8081:8080
```

Comment: more detail for a quick fix to this issue [How to expose a Minkube IP to the Host IP (Kubenate/k8s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71702271/how-to-expose-a-minkube-ip-to-the-host-ip-kubenate-k8s)